# add a symlink to module from project's node_modules

Tags: reactjs

I have a scss folder outside of /src folder in my project structure this is why react angry with bu

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../scss/style.scss which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to
it from project's node_modules/.
```

here is my index.js file:

```
import '../scss/style.scss'


ReactDOM.render(
<HashRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" name="Home Page" component={Full}/>  
    </Switch>
</HashRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and this is the content of style.scss file:

```
// Override Boostrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables";

// Import Bootstrap source files
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Override core variables
@import "core-variables";

// Import core styles
@import "core/core";

// Custom styles
@import "custom";
```

I searched a lot and understood its not allowed to import it outside of /src directory.. how can I "**add a symlink**" as react suggest me to do or how can I fix it other way?

**EDITED**: if i move scss into /src folder:

```
./src/scss/style.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Parent style sheet: stdin
      in D:\Repositories\facereco\src\scss\style.scss (line 14, column 1)
```

Comment: Can't you just add the `scss` file to src? Leaving it outside of src can really mess with bundles, build, etc. If you want to directly import a `scss` from a module, do it inside a `scss` file inside your src folder.

Comment: I tried it throws another exception check edit

Comment: did you find an answer because I am facing ths same error now ? @TyForHelpDude

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do a symlink check the npm documentation. Here is about it https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

In short

- Go to dictionary with your package, in your case your scss file

> `cd ../scss`
>
> `npm link`

- Next go to some other location and:

> `npm link <your_package>`

And you've got it!

Comment: I don't think this works because the OP is not trying to import another npm package. When you do `npm link`, it will walk the tree for the closest `package.json` and assume that is the project you want to link. OP probably needs a traditional symlink, like `ln -s ...`.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this! Thanks. When I first used it and then tried to rebuild my Gatsby project, it didn't seem to be working. Then I realized I needed to run `yarn gatsby clean`. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/build-caching/ Then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the symlink-dir package. If you have for instance a folder called `common` outside of your project root then you can configure package.json with a postinstall script which creates a symlink:

```
"scripts": {
  "link-common": "node_modules/.bin/symlink-dir ../common src/common",
  "postinstall": "npm run link-common"
},
```